# how to create dynamic Spinners in android?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

this code is working fine but its creating only one spinner dynamically i want to get value from database and want to run the loop till database values and generate dynamic Spinner inside the loop overhere i have mentioned the code of **FOR LOOP**  but its not working  and as well as i want to load different item in different spinner please give me idea how to do this?

```
public class DisciplineActivity extends Activity
    {  ArrayList<String> selectDisciplineArrayList,disciplineInfoArrayList;
        @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.discipline_view);
         for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
     disciplineInfoArrayList.add("select location item:"+i);
    }
      // for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    //{
         Spinner disciplineInfoSpinner = new Spinner(this);
         ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                 this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,disciplineInfoArrayList);
         spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

         disciplineInfoSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.disciplineinfo_spinner);
         disciplineInfoSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    }//
    }
```

Comment: ALREADY HAVE MENTIONED WHAT I WANT TO DO

Comment: i want to get value from database and want to run the loop till database values and generate dynamic Spinner inside the loop overhere i have mentioned the code of FOR LOOP but its not working

Comment: your requirement is not that clear. Do you want different `Spinner` for every value???

Comment: YES I WANT DIFFERENT SPINNER FOR EVERY VALUE

Comment: ok.. Follow Leaudro's answer then.. It'll solve your problem and please be kind on that Caps Lock button/Shif key..

Comment: @d3m0li5h3r   have u downvoted my question ? whats wrong with this question ?

Comment: "i want to run the loop till database values" what loop? can you be more clear?

Comment: @user1668447 Question wasnt clear enough plus you could've easily got the answer by a simple google search..

Comment: @d3m0li5h3r  i was trying i m newbie i was not getting the code i can't understand code easily as it is my first project till i m getting error

Comment: @user1668447 there u go.. I've reverted my down vote just because u r a newbie.. Hope next time u'll do a proper research and use the damn search functionality before asking questions..

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new Spinner and doing nothing with it.

You need to create an empty LinearLayout on your "discipline_view" layout, and then add your created Spinners on that LinearLayout, like this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
     Spinner disciplineInfoSpinner = new Spinner(this);
     ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,disciplineInfoArrayList);
     spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

     disciplineInfoSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
     linearLayout.addView(disciplineInfoSpinner);
}
```

Comment: I ALREADY HAVE mentioned my layout in xml and i m putting this in my xml created layout but its not produciong output